# Fill Database from API

Tags: php, api, sqlite

I'm learning how to use PHP and Databases.
Im getting data from an API and filling my DATABASE.

But one of the rows is coming on a weird value. As you can see:

[image]

This is my table structure:
[image]

And if I print the API data you can see the value is reading properly:
[image]

FROM = SENDER

```
<?php
//API Transactions Link
$url = "hiddenurl";
//Translate & Print Json file
$transactions = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

foreach ($transactions->result as $transaction) {
    echo "From: " . $transaction->from . "<br>";
    echo "Value: " . $transaction->value . "<br>";
    echo "Time: " . $transaction->timeStamp . "<br>";
    echo "<hr>";
    mysql_insert("INSERT INTO `api` (`sender`, `amount`, `time`) VALUES ({$transaction->from}, {$transaction->value}, {$transaction->timeStamp});");
}

?>


<?php include 'layout/overall/footer.php'; ?>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: What is the data type of the column sender?

Comment: Is just text and numbers. Im using VARCHAR.

Comment: You show API data of that one record that doesn't have the "weird value". And do we talk about "sender" or "amount" here? I can't see any connection between "sender" (db) and "From" (API). I suppose you'll write a more detailed explanation.

Comment: I'm sorry, SENDER refers to FROM. Its because PHPMyAdmin did not allow me to create a column called from.

Comment: Here is my LOG:

"INSERT INTO `api` (`sender`, `amount`, `time`) VALUES (0xe40238aa7eb773838bcefbad40616db687fc6db1, 1100000000000000000, 1627833157);"

Should be working. Idk must be something very simple I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! Just needed to change VALUES to **''** and not **{}**

For example:

```
mysql_insert("INSERT IGNORE INTO `api` (`sender`, `amount`, `time`) VALUES ('$transaction->from', '$transaction->value', '$transaction->timeStamp');");
```

Instead of:

```
mysql_insert("INSERT IGNORE INTO `api` (`sender`, `amount`, `time`) VALUES ({$transaction->from}, {$transaction->value}, {$transaction->timeStamp});");
```

Thank you all! I knew it was a simple thing.

Answer (score 0):

The value `0xe40238aa7eb773838bcefbad40616db687fc6db1` that you get is binary data in hex form.
The column `sender` should have `BLOB` data type and you should insert its values with:

```
INSERT INTO api (sender, amount, time) VALUES 
(X'e40238aa7eb773838bcefbad40616db687fc6db1', 1100000000000000000, 1627833157);
```

The data in a `BLOB` column are not readable.

Comment: This is not HEX form. It is a cryptocurrency wallet. It's written this way.

Comment: @curbside check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=9d7ad4c9cef353e262356e9f3500c72a If the value was just a common string, it would be displayed fine.

Comment: That's weird. There is no translation for a crypto wallet. They are just like that big numbers and letters. 
I mean can't I just store a bunch of numbers and letters?

Comment: @curbside yes you can if you get *a bunch of numbers and letters* as a string. But in this case you get binary data.

Comment: But I have the same "binary" in another table, but this time user type it when registering and database is reading just fine. Is there a way to say to database that this is a string? If I add "e40238aa7eb773838bcefbad40616db687fc6db1" manually into the sender ROW database reads it fine as well.